# Finding documentation and/or full list of possible return values for the type= attribute of raw location in Geopy?

Tags: python, geopy

I'm trying to classify addresses into their respective types. To do that, I'm running the address through Geopy to find the complete address, and then I am pulling the attribute 'type' from the raw output of the file.

This is basically the code I am using:

```
final_address = address.apply(geocode)
type = final_address.apply(lambda loc: loc.raw['type'] if loc else None)
```

The code works fine; it returns things like 'house', 'courthouse', etc., but there are also some entries that return things like 'secondary'. I'm not completely sure what that is, and I was hoping to find some documentation on the full list of possible things 'type' can return. I saw some page on [OpenStreetMap Wiki](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_features) talking about their map features, but I am not completely sure where those features are located in Geopy.

I've also looked through Geopy and Nominatim documentation to no avail.

I appreciate any insights!

Comment: There might not be a fixed list of types.